# django how to return classBasedView from in a function

Tags: python, django

I am trying to put a condition before the password reset view, so I want to return it from a function based view.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

def password_reset(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if some condition:
            Do something
        else:
            return (
                auth_views.PasswordResetView(
                    **{
                        'template_name': 'reset-form.html',
                        'email_template_name': 'reset-email.txt',
                        'html_email_template_name': 'reset-email.html',
                        'subject_template_name': 'reset_subject.txt',
                        'form_class': PasswordResetForm,
                        'success_url': 'etc...',
                    }
                ),
            )
```

With this code I get `'tuple' object does not support item assignment` error.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you considered creating a subclass of PasswordResetView?

Comment: If I create a subclass of PasswordResetView, can I put a condition before rendering?

Comment: Yeah, that would be how I'd do it.